# Syntax and pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

Just looking through a word frequency count program from my textbook, I'm having 
a little trouble understanding a few segments.

I get the general gist of the function, we're getting a word from stdin and returning
1 if we find a word, 0 if not.

Now, is `if (strchr(wordChars,ch)) break;` this line just saying, "if the char we 
grabbed from stdin is part of the alphabet we're breaking the loop?

Following, `*c++ = ch;` this line confuses me, is this setting the first character
to the second element of the string? Why would you want to do this?

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    ch = tolower(ch);
    if (!strchr(wordChars,ch)) break;
    *c++ = ch;
```

This is the meat of the function, yes? Where we form the actual word. Also, 
`if (c == buf) return 0;` I'm assuming this line is to catch when nothing or 
a non-alphabetic input is read.

The syntax here is confusing, is \' a character? It would seem to me that this
element of the string hasn't been initialized yet. If we leave that, 
the rest of the code is where we shift the word we got back an element, this 
doesn't really make sense to me.

```
if (buf[0] == '\'') {
    for (c = buf+1; *c != '\0'; c++)
        *(c-1) = *c;
    *(c-1) = '\0';
}
```

Next, isn't this accessing and replacing
the last letter of the word? It would make sense to me
if strlen include the null character, but it doesn't right?

```
n = strlen(buf)-1;
```

I guess the real thing I want to get out of this is what '\'' is meant to convey.

Thanks for any help!**

```
int getWord(char *buf){

    int ch, n;
    char *c = buf;
    const char *wordChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'";

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ch = tolower(ch);
        if (strchr(wordChars,ch)) break;
    }
    if (ch == EOF) return 0;
    *c++ = ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ch = tolower(ch);
        if (!strchr(wordChars,ch)) break;
        *c++ = ch;
    }
    *c = '\0';
    if (c == buf) return 0;
    if (buf[0] == '\'') {
        for (c = buf+1; *c != '\0'; c++)
            *(c-1) = *c;
        *(c-1) = '\0';
    }
    n = strlen(buf)-1;
    if (buf[n] == '\'') {
        buf[n] = '\0';
    }
    else if (buf[n-1] == '\'' && buf[n] == 's') {
        buf[n-1] = '\0';
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `'\''` means a single quote mark. The \ symbol means "The following character is not literally that character but has special meaning". In this case the special meaning is because `'` is normally indicating the end of the character constant, i.e. `''` would be an error. The \ says that the following `'` is meant to be what's inside the delimiters, not a delimiter itself.

Comment: Postfix `++` returns the original value of the variable, therefore the line `*c++ = ch;` is really equivalent to:  `*c = ch; c += 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow so many questions! I'll try to answer them all.

`Now, is 'if (strchr(wordChars,ch)) break;' this line just saying, "if the char we grabbed from stdin is part of the alphabet we're breaking the loop?`

Yes. From [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/): "If the character is not found, the function returns a null pointer." So if `ch` is not found in `wordChars` then `strchr` returns `NULL`, which is equivalent to `0`.

`Following, '*c++ = ch;' this line confuses me, is this setting the first character to the second element of the string? Why would you want to do this?`

No. This sets the first character to the *first* element of the string, and *then* increments the string pointer. (Technically, this is not quite right--really what's happening is that the pointer is being incremented, but then the operator returns the *old* pointer, and that is what's being set.) This occurs repeatedly, writing the new `ch` to the end of the string.

`Also, 'if (c == buf) return 0;' I'm assuming this line is to catch when nothing or a non-alphabetic input is read.`

That's correct.

`The syntax here is confusing, is \' a character? It would seem to me that this element of the string hasn't been initialized yet.`

What would the compiler think if you typed `'''`? It would see `''`, which is an invalid character (as you don't have anything between the apostrophes), and then another `'`, which would remain unmatched. The `\` is the escape character. `\'` basically means "compiler, don't treat this apostrophe as the ending delimiter of the character -- treat it *as* the character!"

`If we leave that, the rest of the code is where we shift the word we got back an element, this doesn't really make sense to me.`

Basically what you are doing here is going from character #1 all the way to the end of the word and moving characters back one index, one by one. Then, you have to null-terminate your string with the `\0`. (Note that the `\` here is also the escape character. You might want to look this up to see more examples. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)'s a reference.)

`Next, isn't this accessing and replacing the last letter of the word? It would make sense to me if strlen include the null character, but it doesn't right?`

It *is* replacing the last character of the word. Specifically, it is replacing it with the null terminator, effectively removing that last character. Basically, this and the last section of code are just removing an apostrophe from the beginning and end of the word.

I hope this helps! Please ask any more questions you have! :)

Comment: Never mind I just re read your answer and you already answered my questions, thank you so much! Perfectly explained.

Answer (score 3):

To address this code snippet:

```
if (strchr(wordChars,ch)) break;
```

your guess is correct. This means that if the character ch is found in the string wordChars, a pointer to the location of the character is returned by strchr(). The above snippet, in this case, can be simplified to:

```
if (!NULL) break;
```

because a non-null pointer is returned. The statement evaluates to true (as NULL == 0 evaluates to false, and !false evaluates to true) and a break statement is hit.

To address your question about the backslash, the backslash '\' character in C signifies an [escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C). From the link:

> An escape sequence is a sequence of characters that does not represent itself when used inside a character or string literal, but is translated into another character or a sequence of characters that may be difficult or impossible to represent directly.

In this case, '\0' signifies the end of a null-terminated string, and is called the **null character**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, and I will read more on escape sequences. The problem I'm having is with this escape sequence, if (buf[0] == '\'') {  what does the '\'' represent? I'm sure this is not a string literal. Thanks again if you get around to responding.

Comment: Because the single-quote is a bit of a special character in C, any time you want to use it as a literal (in this case, finding an instance of a single-quote in a string literal) you need to escape it with a backslash. \' basically means "treat that single-quote as a literal single-quote, not a special character in C". Therefore, the statement if (buf[0] == '\'') {...} means "if the character at the 0th index of buf is a single-quote, do the stuff in the body of this if statement".

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for clearing that up David, that's one more piece of syntax I won't have to worry about any more.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help :)